# Damaged Connector Identification

Tags: connector, identification, surface-mount

[image: Broken Connector Image]

This connector got damaged while repairing a device, and I've been unable to identify it to replace it.

The connector is SMD mounted with the circuit board underneath based on the image above. It is 1mm pitch and has (had) 5 pins. The cable connects/disconnects by lifting vertically away from the PCB.

Socket dimensions: 7.8mm x 4.5mm x 1.4mm, 1mm pitch, pins are 1mm long 0.2mm thick.

Plug dimensions; 7.1mm x 3.7mm x 1.2mm, the cable ends appear to be crimped.

Better image:
[image: Higher res connector image]

Cable end (the empty connection was always empty, the connector has space for five connections, only four are used):
[image: Cable Image]

Comment: Need more focus.

Comment: I've added the new images

Comment: Need pin pitch and connector dimensions, measured with calipers.

Comment: I've added the dimensions, my calipers are cheap so they are all +/- 0.1mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Molex Pico EZMATE header [WM4461CT-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0781710005/WM4461CT-ND/2424930) and the plug [WM4462-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0781720005/WM4462-ND/2424927). Those are Digi-Key numbers as I found them there but Molex parts are available all over. Pitch on these two parts is 1.20MM

[image] [image]